# When an ideal is generated by idempotents 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals, idempotents

As in my previous question [When an ideal is generated by idempotents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267509/when-an-ideal-is-generated-by-idempotents/2268131#2268131). Let $I$ be a **finitely generated** ideal of a commutative ring $R$ with identity such that for all prime ideals $P$ of $R$ with $I\not\subseteq P$ and each $n\in
\mathbb{N}$, $ I\subseteq (P+I)^{n}$. Can we show that $I$ is generated by idempotents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take for example $R=k[x]/(x^2)$, with $k$ a field. Then $R$ is a local ring with maximal ideal $(x)$.

Take $I=(x)$. Then it's trivially true that for all prime ideals $P$ such that $I$ is not in $P$ we have $I \subseteq (P+I)^n$, but $x$ is not an idempotent.

More generally, one can construct a counterexample using any local ring with maximal ideal not generated by an idempotent.

EDIT: To give another counterexample when the set of primes not containing $I$ is nonempty, take $R=k[x]/(x(x+1))$, $k$ a field and $I=(x)$. Then the only prime not containing $I$ in $R$ is the prime $P=(x+1)$. But $I$ is not contained in $P$ and $I$ and $P$ generate the unit ideal, so again the condition is trivially satisfied.

My guess is that any variation of the statement with a hope to be true would have to assume that $I$ is not prime.

Comment: This is rather a nitpick, than an answer, suggesting the OP to exclude such trivial cases.

Comment: @user26857 I mean it's a counterexample to the statement as written, is it not? I don't see a way to fix the statement, unless you exclude cases like these ad hoc

Comment: I guess one could require that $I$ be non maximal. Or not prime. In any case I'll accept that my answer is nitpicky, but it all depends on how OP would like to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and let $I=2\mathbb{Z}$. All prime ideals $P$ distinct from $I$ satisfy $I\subseteq (P+I)^{n}$ for all $n$. But $I$ cannot be generated by idempotents, as the only idempotents in $R$ are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: The question is trivially true for domains. In this case, $I $ must be the zero ideal.

Comment: You're right, I missed the zero ideal. Please disregard my answer.